# unit testing for component containing dynamically loaded component

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a component and I have dynamically loaded other component inside this component.
I am struggling to write unit test cases for angular component.
Unable to find reading material on this topic.

In my component I have :

```
const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
```

In the spec file I am getting this error,

```
{
    "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught Error: No component factory found for TestComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents? thrown",
    "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught Error: No component factory found for TestComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents? thrown"
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have tried to implement as components and their tests.

Comment: Try not to generalize and code it like component A and component B. A small snippet of code (original) would be helpful for us to take a look and let you know the solution.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Also, since I am using ComponentFactoryResolver from @angular/core I do not think I have to handle it differently

Comment: Specifically I am trying to figure out test bed configuration changes in component when componentFactoryResolver is used in it.